# How to return object that matches using es6 map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

trying to use es6 map method so below i am trying to get object from cacheDetails function that matches with the key but it also returns some undefined values, what is implemented wrong in below code any help would be appreciated ?

main.js

```
var uniqueCacheKeys = [{key:"14556459709"},{key:"1457099"}];
var rxInfos = [];
function getCahce(data){
  data.forEach(function(el){
    var rxInfo = cacheDetails(el.key);
    if(rxInfo){
      rxInfos.push(rxInfo);
    } 
  });
}
function cacheDetails(key){
  var mapObj;
   var rxInfos = [
      {
            "drugNdc": "10101",
            "rxNumber": "14556459709",
            "firstFillIndicator": "N",
            "sourceSystem": "TBS",
            "indexID": "RPT0ifQ",
            "ancilary": true
        },{
            "drugNdc": "10101",
            "rxNumber": "145709",
            "firstFillIndicator": "N",
            "sourceSystem": "TBS",
            "indexID": "RPT0ifQ",
            "ancilary": true
        }];
  mapObj = rxInfos.map(function (task, index, array) {
   if(task.rxNumber === key){
        return task; 
   }
});

  return mapObj;
}
getCahce(uniqueCacheKeys);

console.log(rxInfos);
```

output

```
[[[object Object] {
  ancilary: true,
  drugNdc: "10101",
  firstFillIndicator: "N",
  indexID: "RPT0ifQ",
  rxNumber: "14556459709",
  sourceSystem: "TBS"
}, undefined], [undefined, undefined]]
```

desired ouput with above data

```
[{
  ancilary: true,
  drugNdc: "10101",
  firstFillIndicator: "N",
  indexID: "RPT0ifQ",
  rxNumber: "14556459709",
  sourceSystem: "TBS"
}]
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` is ES5 (the es6 feature is a `Map`, which behaves similarly to an object)

Comment: Your `.map` function is only sometimes returning values - when it doesn't, you get `undefined`. Use `filter` instead of `map`

Comment: @CertainPerformance i wanted to return object {} filter returns array

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: desired output would be if any object keys matched push that object to rxInfos array.

Comment: Please explain better, that doesn't make much sense by itself - post the desired data structure in your question

Comment: @CertainPerformance added desired output to the question

Comment: Use `filter`, as in the linked question, then because `cacheDetails` will return an array, check `if(rxInfo.length){` instead of `if(rxInfo){`, and spread into `rxInfos`

Comment: `.map` only makes sense when you want to construct a new array from *every element* of another. If you want to *pick particular elements* from one array to construct another, use `filter`

Comment: thank you for the explanation i got the idea i think.